# Android Facebook minimum API level error

Tags: android, facebook

I'm implementing Facebook SDK into my App.

Following the facebook developers guide, except I do not have GIT set up, so I've downloaded the SDK, and imported it to Eclipse, changed Java compliance level to 1.6.

In file Facebook.java, on one method "AutoPublishAsynchTask" I constantly have error:

Call requires API level 3 (current min is 1): android.os.AsyncTask#

How to get rid of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **android:minSdkVersion** of manifest to 8 or more then 3 , then it will work.
The problem is **AsyncTask** is introduced from level 3 for that reason you getting the error.

Comment: Tnx. Did that, now it looks good. I do not understand, as this is Library project, shouldn't it check minSdkVersion of "main" project that includes it? ... how ever, it looks good now.